# Automapper rounding down decimal / removing precision

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, automapper

I'm mapping an entity model onto a UI model, however after the mapping is done, several fields are being rounded down. All the affected fields are of the same type **decimal?** , when pulling it from the database the field is 8245.82 however once mapped it's 8245.00

```
public IActionResult View(Guid Id)
{
     try
     {
           DealEx entity = _dealService.Get(m => m.Id == Id);
           var model = _mapper.Map<DealUI>(entity);
           AddReferenceData(model);
           return PartialView("_deal", model);
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           this.ProcessException(ex, _logger);
           return View("Error");
        }
}
```

I'm assuming this is something within Automapper? When the **entity** model is pulled out the value is correct, I then map it and the value in **model** is now rounded down.

It's probably also worth mentioning that DealUI inherits DealEx .

```
public class DealUI : DealEx
{
    public DealUI()
    {
    }

    // just some select lists in here , northing of interest to this 
}
```

```
public class DealEx
{
   public DealEx(){}

   public decimal? BillValue {get; set;}

   // obivously alot more in this model but it's a big ole model so copying  it all seems a bit pointless
}
```

Including the mapping to be concise

```
 CreateMap<DealEx, DealUI>();
 CreateMap<DealUI, DealEx>();
```

Cheers

Comment: A repro would help. Make a [gist](https://gist.github.com/lbargaoanu/9c7233441c3a3413cc2b9b9ebb5964a9) that we can execute and see fail.

Comment: adding DealEx , DealUI and the mapper would help.

Comment: sorry i misunderstood your question first time, i've now added . Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<NameOfEntity>()
                    .Property(p => p.NameOfProperty)
                    .HasPrecision(9, 4); // or whatever your schema specifies
    }
```

Comment: Hi Kasper, thanks for the help. I'm actually using MariaDb and the decimal is (65,30) .

Comment: I have updated my answer to have a bit of code you can try

Comment: I've just had a look and it seems the SqlProviderServices is for SqlServer am i right in thinking this? ... Either way , when pulling the values from the database they are correct (albeit with trailing 0s) , it's only when mapping them are they rounded down.

Comment: Wait a second, your decimal precision is set to (65,30)? I am not sure you can have a decimal that big

Comment: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-decimal/    It seems you can, this must be the default in MariaDb

Comment: do you need your decimal to be that big?

Comment: Definitely not , it seems to be the default when migrating. (I've only noticed it when you asked). But I don't think this is the issue.